# Android EditText & Dialogbox

Tags: java, android, datepicker, textview, android-edittext

I've implemented an android screen with an Edittext. When the user touches this EditText, a datepickerdialog appears. This all worked fine, however my problem is that when the user touches the EditText, two datepickerdialogs are appearing. I only want one to appear.

I' wondering if anyone has encountered this problem, or is it only me? If yes, are there any solutions? I Google'd it, however found nothing :/

With regards to code, this is what I have:

```
        datebox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.datebox);

    datebox.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 

    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            timedatedialog(false);
            return false;
        }});

public void timedatedialog(boolean flag) {

         if(flag==false){

               DatePickerDialog dateDlg = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {
                Time chosenDate = new Time();
                chosenDate.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
                long dtDob = chosenDate.toMillis(true);
                CharSequence strDate = DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", dtDob);

                Toast.makeText(ForecastingActivity.this,
                        "Date picked: " + strDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                datebox.setText(strDate);

            }}, 2012,0, 1);
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try changing the return to true from onTouch() method. Look at this documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29

Comment: Then check if the onTouch() method is being called twice with different event Types by debugging the code. If yes, then make sure you perform for only one action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `OnTouchListener` to an `OnClickListener` or similiar. The `onTouch()`-method is invoked for any kind of touch event,  i.e:
if you click the view you will go into `onTouch()` with a down-event,
and then if you happen move your finger the slightest you will go into `onTouch()` with a move-action, 
and finally you lift your finger and get `onTouch()` again, this time with a up-event.

The `OnClickListener` on the other hand only runs once, if you click the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know what happen..

```
 datebox.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
         if((arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
          {
            timedatedialog(false);
          }
            return false;
        }});
```

Or just change to it `onClickListener()` method of your EditText..